# return возвращает NULL

Tags: php

Почему функция возвращает NULL? Если сделать дамп в функции перед словом return тогда выводится ожидаемый масив, при дампе функции tree_menu() - NULL.

```
<? 
function tree_menu($menu, $parent = 0){
    static $key_1 = 0;
    static $key_2 = 0;
    static $key_3 = 0;
    static $key_4 = 0;
    static $arResult;

    switch($menu[$parent]['DEPTH_LEVEL']) {
        case 1:
            $key_1++; 
            $arResult[$key_1]=$menu[$parent];
        break;
        case 2:
            $key_2++;
            $arResult[$key_1]['CHILDRENS'][$key_2]=$menu[$parent];
        break;
        case 3:
            $key_3++;
            $arResult[$key_1]['CHILDRENS'][$key_2]['CHILDRENS'][$key_3]=$menu[$parent];
        break;
        case 4:
            $key_4++;
            $arResult[$key_1]['CHILDRENS'][$key_2]['CHILDRENS'][$key_3]['CHILDRENS'][$key_4]=$menu[$parent];
        break;
    }
    $parent++;
    if(empty($menu[$parent])){
        return $arResult;
    }else{
        tree_menu($menu,$parent);
    }
}

$a = tree_menu($arResult);
var_dump($a);
?>
```

Comment: Не по теме вопроса - не используйте короткие php-теги `<?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что возврат из функции перед `var_dump()` происходит...

```
if(empty($menu[$parent])){
    return $arResult;
}else{
    tree_menu($menu,$parent); // <--- ... вот ТУТ
}
```

Вы в этой строке забыли `return`, а функции PHP без `return` возвращают по-умолчанию `null`

Comment: как мне записать в переменную $a значение которое возвращает return $arResult?

Comment: @ПетроЧайківський У вас там рекурсия, но вы не возвращаете на предыдущий шаг рекурсии значение. Напишите `return tree_menu($menu,$parent);` вместо `tree_menu($menu,$parent);`